# Replacing a tab with a different one using JS

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I have something in place that opens a new tab with some html code, using

```
    const winUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([final_file], { type: "text/html;charset=utf8" }));
    const win = window.open(winUrl);
```

where final_file is some html that I generate. I want to make it so instead of opening a new tab every time, if such a tab is already open, it should replace it. I tried using frame names in window.open, but I was told that they are deprecated and shouldn't be used.
What do I do?

Comment: *"I was told that they are deprecated"* Where did you get that information?

Comment: I got that information from https://html.com/attributes/a-target/#:~:text=browser%20specifies%20otherwise.-,a%20target%3D%E2%80%9D_blank%E2%80%9D%20Open%20in%20New%20Browser%20Tab%20(,older%20browsers)%20a%20new%20window.

Comment: I would not rely on that site for any information. There's a difference between a frame and a named tab/window. Consult MDN instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: @PlainXYZ Yes, `<frame>` is deprecated. But that is not `target` attribute, do not mix it

Comment: Ok, I just don't have a-lot of experience in all of that, and since it called the target framename I thought it had something to do with frames. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place dedicated window name (`target` as second argument to `.open`) to your opened window, so browser would know to replace it instead of opening new window:

```js
    const winUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([final_file], { type: "text/html;charset=utf8" }));
    const win = window.open(winUrl, 'my-window');
```

---

[`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#target) is not deprecated.

Comment: This is very close to what I need, but this also overrides the tab that opens that windows for some reason, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out, apparently I was using a bad window name so it didn't work, thanks!